# How to unit test a component with TranslateService

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I followed this very carefully:
[Git issue #636](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636).

But I'm not able to solve my problem. Let me explain. I've a `TimeSelector` component for which I've externalized all strings in a file `i18n/en-US.json`. Initially when the page loads, I'm setting `recievedFromChild` variable with `CY 2020 VS CY 2019`. Where `CY` and `VS` I've stored in `en-US.json`. So, when the page loads I'm calling `translate.get([...]).subscribe(...)`. And I'm trying to test this thing only. Here's the code:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<div>{{recievedFromChild}}</div>
```

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ... } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-timeselector',
    templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html'
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    calendarYearLabel: string;
    versusLabel: string;

    date = new Date();
    currentYear = this.date.getFullYear();
    previousYear= (this.date.getFullYear())-1;

    recievedFromChild; // <=========================== THIS I WANT TO TEST

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService,...) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.translateModes();
    }

    translateModes(): void {
      this.translate
        .get([
            'Timeselection.Abbreviations.CalendarYear',
            'Timeselection.Abbreviations.Versus'
        ])
        .subscribe(translations => {
          this.calendarYearLabel=translations['Timeselection.Abbreviations.CalendarYear'];
          this.versusLabel = translations['Timeselection.Abbreviations.Versus'];
          this.recievedFromChild =
              this.calendarYearLabel +
              ' ' +
              this.currentYear +
              ' ' +
              this.versusLabel +
              ' ' +
              this.calendarYearLabel +
              ' ' +
              this.previousYear;
        });
    }    
}
```

This is the external file: **en-US.json**

```
"Timeselection": {
    "Abbreviations": {
      "CalendarYear": "CY",   
      "Versus": "VS"
    }
}
```

and here's my test file: **timeselector.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { TimeselectorComponent } from './timeselector.component'
...
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...

fdescribe('TimeselectorComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TimeselectorComponent>;

    let mockTranslateService;

    beforeEach(async(()=>{
        mockTranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['get']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService},
                ...
            ],
            declarations: [
                ...
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimeselectorComponent);

    }))

    it('should create', ()=> {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
    })

    // THIS IS THE TEST CASE    
    it('should initially display current and previous calendar years only', () => {
        //fixture.componentInstance.translateModes();
        //fixture.detectChanges(); 
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.recievedFromChild).toBe('CY 2020 VS CY 2019');
    })
})
```

But I'm getting this failed test case:

> TypeError: this.translate.get(...) is undefined

Here's the screenshot of the test case:

[image]

Please tell me what to do now. I'm blocked.

Comment: Did you try something like: `mockTranslateService.get.and.returnValue(of(mockdata))`, after `mockTranslateService = jasmine...` ?

Comment: Now I'm getting: `Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js `

Comment: i replaced `..of(mockdata))` with `..of(true))`

Comment: Looks like the new problem is related to some forms you're using.

Comment: I'm using an input field with `ngModel`

Comment: Considering the error, I'd assume you're using a custom component that should act as a form control and you didn't provide a `CVA` for it.

Comment: Exactly. You are correct.